# Returning error indication when flask POST Request fails

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a simple flask application that takes a string from an iOS application and stores it in a local data base.  I'm a bit confused whats happening in the `return` portion of the `submitPost()` function.  I'm trying to return a dictionary that contains a BOOL that indicates whether the Post request executed fully.  However, i'm not sure how to variate between returning a 0 or a 1.

```
//Function that handles the Post request
@app.route('/submitPost/', methods=['POST'])
def submitPost():
    post = Post.from_json(request.json)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(post.to_json), {'Success': 1}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below. This way if an exception is thrown when trying to insert data it will be caught and the transaction will be rolled back as well as a response being send back.

you could also replace the zero and one with True & False depending on your preference

Below code hasn't been tested

```
@app.route('/submitPost/', methods=['POST'])
def submitPost():
    try:
        post = Post.from_json(request.json)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'Success': 1})
    except Exception:     # replace with a more meaningful exception
        db.session.rollback()
        return jsonify{'Failure': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, for the exception, is it necessary to include `jsonify`?

Comment: I guess it would depend on your situation but generally I would say yes so that who ever made the submit knows that they were unsuccessful in there attempt to insert data. you could also add a message to the return  with a brief explanation as to the failure or a message to contact the site admin. otherwise the user may be unsure if their post was successful or if something else happen.

Comment: Is `jsonify` just converting the dictionary `{'Success': 1}` to JSON?